# python moving multiple files from one folder to the other based on text characters in file name

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm quite new to *Python*.  I've been exploring the `shutil` module and can move things in general.  My question revolves around:

Imagine a scenario in which you have hundreds of files in an export folder.  While all the files are distinct, 13 of each are for a specific vendor.  I would like to create a script that goes through the export folder, evaluates each file name, grabs all the Apple files and puts them in the Apple Folder, Intel files and puts them in the Intel Folder, etc.  Any wisdom would be greatly appreciated.

I was trying to have wildcards in the `shutil` copy, but did not have any luck.

Thanks,

JT

Comment: Do all the *Apple* files actually contain the string *Apple*, and similar for *Intel*, etc?

Comment: what distinguishes the files into each category?

Comment: Thank you for your question. All the files will have Applex.xlsx, Applebig.xlsx, intelx.xlsx, intelbig.xlsx, etc.  There will never be confusion in that a string would have apple and intel.  I just want to ignore the rest of the strings except for the common element and then drop those in an Apple folder (roughly 13 files).  All of the files have headers such that you can't sort all the apple files together easily.

Comment: so you just want the apple?

Comment: I would like to learn how to have this for 2 cases (apple, intel in this example) so I can see the mechanics and understand how it differs from 1 case and expand it to n cases as appropriate.

Answer (score 24):

Easiest solution I could think of:

```
import shutil
import os

source = '/path/to/source_folder'
dest1 = '/path/to/apple_folder'
dest2 = '/path/to/intel_folder'

files = os.listdir(source)

for f in files:
    if (f.startswith("Apple") or f.startswith("apple")):
        shutil.move(f, dest1)
    elif (f.startswith("Intel") or f.startswith("intel")):
        shutil.move(f, dest2)
```

The destination folders **do** need to exist.

Comment: Wouldn't `shutil.move` need to path and filename to `f`, not just the filename?

Comment: In order to get this to work for me I had to do os.chdir(source) after the import of os and shutil.move(os.path.abspath(f), dest1). Per what Herbet mentioned above I think the f variable only represents the filename and not the full path. os.path.abspath(f) will take care of that for you.

Answer (score 3):

```
import glob, shutil

for file in glob.glob('path_to_dir/apple*'):
    shutil.move(file, new_dst)


# a list of file types
vendors =['path_to_dir/apple*', 'path_to_dir/intel*'] 

for file in vendors:
     for f in (glob.glob(file)): 
         if "apple" in f: # if apple in name, move to new apple dir
             shutil.move(f, new_apple_dir)
         else:
             shutil.move(f, new_intel_dir) # else move to intel dir
```

Comment: yargh!  I couldn't get either method to work for me.  I will tinker with when I get home.  Thank you for your kind thoughts 189 and Padraic!

Comment: No worries, I will add a way to do a list of different files

Comment: I tried the following, but no luck:   import glob, shutil


for file in glob.glob('C:/Users/r6/Desktop/a/apple*'):
    shutil.move(file, 'C:/Users/r6/Desktop/b/')


# a list of file types
vendors =['C:/Users/r6/Desktop/a/apple*', 'C:/Users/r6/Desktop/a/intel*'] 

for file in vendors:
     for f in (glob.glob(file)): 
         if "apple" in f: # if apple in name, move to new apple dir
             shutil.move(f, 'C:/Users/r6/Desktop/b/')
         else:
             shutil.move(f, 'C:/Users/r6/Desktop/b/') # else move to intel dir

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there are specific strings in the file names that identify which vendor the report relates to, you could create a dictionary that maps those identifying-strings to the appropriate vendor.  For example:

```
import shutil
import os

path = '/path/to/location'

vendorMap = {'apple': 'Apple', 
             'intel': 'Intel', 
             'stringID3': 'vendor3'}

files = os.listdir(path)

for f in files:
    for key, value in vendorMap.iteritems():
        if key in f.lower():
            shutil.copy(f, path + '/' + value)
        else:
            print 'Error identifying vendor for', f
```

This will create a folder in the current directory, named for the appropriate vendor, and copy that vendor's reports there.  Note that this example uses the [s.lower()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) method so that it won't matter whether the vendor name is capitalized.

Comment: os.listdir() will list directories as well as files. It may be worth checking that f is a file rather than a directory before attempting to copy it.

Answer (score 1):

Minor edit on Padaic's answer:

```
import glob
import shutil

vendors = ("*Apple*.*", "*Intel*.*")
paths = (".\\Apple\\", ".\\Intel\\")
for idx in range(len(vendors)):
    for matches in glob.glob(vendors[idx]):
        shutil.move(matches, paths[idx])
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below is working for me -

```
import os
import shutil


ent_dir_path = input("Enter the path of the directory:") #source directory


out_dir_path = input("Enter the path of the directory where you want to move all these files:")  #destination directory

if not os.path.exists(out_dir_path):  #create folder if doesn't exist
    os.makedirs(out_dir_path)


file_type = input("Enter the first few characters of type of file you want to move:") 

entries = os.listdir(ent_dir_path)

for entry in entries:
     if entry.startswith(file_type):
         #print(ent_dir_path + entry)
         shutil.move(ent_dir_path + entry, out_dir_path)

# ent_dir_path + entry is the path of the file you want to move 
# example-   entry = Apple.txt  
#            ent_dir_path = /home/user/Downloads/
#            ent_dir_path + entry = /home/user/Downloads/Apple.txt  (path of the 
#            file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Andreas's answer is fine for the Apples example you've given. If you're looking for something more meaty, check out regexs. They let you search for repeating patterns of text.

Where I work, for example, we have different formats of text depending on whether the file is a report, or a technical drawing etc. They all follow a format similar to "company initials/project number/department.

As a regex, you could search something like:

```
import re

fileregex = re.compile(r'(\w\w)/(\d{4})/(\w\w))
for file in os.listdir(*path*):
    filename = fileregex.search(file)
```

It's a handy tool to know.