# How to move same numbers of files in different folders using Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a folder with a lot of csv files I can manipulate them quite easily with `for file in Path(folder).glob('*.csv'):` and pandas where folder is the path of the folder.

But now I have to move those files in folders named like "folder1", "folder2", "folder3"...

I want there to be the same number of files in each folder plus or minus 1 file because if the number of files does not divide the number of folders there will be 1 more file in some.

I **can't** do it using `.startswith` because I have like 20 folders and files don't begin like I want.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: It is not clear what is your main problem ? The moving file part or the "division" ? And I don't see why you would want to use startswith ?

Comment: Hey it's the division, I spoke about startswith because I can't use it, since the names of my files are not compatible, in case someone offered me a solution like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25070614/python-moving-multiple-files-from-one-folder-to-the-other-based-on-text-characte

Comment: Ok I still think I'm missing something so let my try to rephrase it : You want to move ALL the .csv files in your folder in several folders but you don't have a specific rule about which files end up in which folder right ? Only that each folder should have more or less the same number of files at the end ?

Comment: you have `3` folders and `10` files, you want the files to be divided evenly so you have `3` files in each folder with `1` remainder, what happens to the `1` remaining file? I agree with Viper the question is not clear at all.

Comment: Sorry I'm not native english, it's like u said Umar.H except that the first folder contain 4 files. It is clear now ? "but you don't have a specific rule about which files end up in which folder right" --> Yeah so i can't use what i put in the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution can be this function which returns a list of file counts, one for each folder:

```
def d(numfiles, numfolders):
    result = [numfiles // numfolders] * numfolders
    for i in range(numfiles % numfolders):
        result[i] += 1
    return result

print(d(10, 3))
```

Prints:

```
[4, 3, 3]
```

Comment: Hey thanks ! I succeeded it with your function, I will edit and put all the code :)